# When I pushes ssh in GitHub repo, not my username displaying

Tags: git, github, https, ssh

Is not an important issue but when I pushes using the https protocol (so git ask me for username and password), on GitHub, I can see my GitHub username.

and when I pushes with the ssh protocl (I have set the ssh key in GitHub settings but I have set my real name in the git binary settings because of my job) I can see my real name and so no the link to my profil and not avatar for me :(

Can someone explain me how to resolve this problem without changing my real name in the git binary of just change it for a specified repo ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you want to check: https://github.com/RaphyTheGeek/Templyz/commits/master
See the commit authors

Answer (score 1):

When you do your commit, you have to set up your user name/mail by typing:

```
git config --global user.name "The name you want to show in your commits"
git config --global user.email "Mail used with GitHub account or another mail you'll add to your GitHub accout"
```

Comment: That's correct! But I guess only the mail adress is needed :) Thanks.

Comment: If you want to do the modifications only for a specified repository just type '--local' insteand of '--global'

Comment: @RaphyTheGeek Setting the name using the `git config` command is still recommended as it sets the name that will appear when people run the `git log` command, or in case you change the email address associated with your Github account